# Flutter - issue sending form post with child map attribute

Tags: forms, http, post, flutter

I am trying to send a POST request in the following JSON format, however, as the Http package does not accept dynamic as a value I am getting an error listed below.

Any suggestions how I can fix this in Flutter?

```
{
   "username": "john",
   "password": "XXXX",
   "deviceName": "XXX",
   "attributes": {
       "deviceName": "iPhone Xʀ",
       "deviceVersion" : "12.2",
       "identifier": "XXX",
       "notificationToken": "XXX",
       "os": "XXX"
   }
}
```

Error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
#0      CastMap.forEach.<anonymous closure> (dart:_internal/cast.dart:286:25)
```

Below is the code I am using to try submit the JSON above

```
http.Response response = await http.post(
      uri,
      headers: headers,
      body: data,
      encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
    );
```

data is variable for the JSON.

Here is the Http package I am using : https://pub.dev/packages/http

Comment: hell try this to your data variable >> json.encode(map) and also try to add this to your post request >> headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`body` must be one of:

- A `Map<String, String>` which will be sent as form data encoded as `x-www-form-urlencoded`
- A `List<int>` which will be sent as raw bytes
- A `String` which will be encoded to bytes in UTF-8

You need to encode your JSON to a string yourself (and optionally encode it in a character encoding, if you want a specific one), for example:

```
http.post(
  uri,
  headers: headers,
  body: json.encode(data),
  encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
);
```

You may also need to add a header specifying the `content-type` as `application/json;charset=utf-8` - maybe you already are.

Comment: I had the same problem.
It was resolved after adding `encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')`.

Answer (score -1):

u can use this code to fetch that

```dart
var response = await http.get(url);
// Logs the response body to the console
print(response.body);
// To modify the state of the app, use this method
setState(() {
  // Get the JSON data var dataConvertedToJSON = 
  json.decode(response.body);
  data = dataConvertedToJSON[data you want to get];
});
```

Comment: var response = await http.get(url);
      // Logs the response body to the console
      print(response.body);

      // To modify the state of the app, use this method
      setState(() {
        // Get the JSON data
        var dataConvertedToJSON = json.decode(response.body);
      data = dataConvertedToJSON['data'];

Comment: Hi Wael,

Thank you for your answer, the problem I am having is, http.post() only accepts Map with <String, String> however I need to submit <String, dynamic> as my fields can have their own Map fields and values. I hope that helps